# Natural sort of a list of lists based on an alphanumeric string within sub-list?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, natural-sort

Clear as mud, aye?  I'll start with an example...

```
my_list = [[4,'A4, A23, A3, A6', 'Description 1', 'Property 1'],
           [4,'B3, B35, B10, B22', 'Description 2', 'Property 2'],
           [6,'A1, A11, A10, A21, A2, A22', 'Description 3', 'Property 3']]
```

Should sort to:

```
>>>my_list:
[[6,'A1, A2, A10, A11, A21,  A22', 'Description 3', 'Property 3'] 
 [4,'A3, A4, A6, A23', 'Description 1', 'Property 1'],
 [4,'B3, B10, B22, B35', 'Description 2', 'Property 2']]
```

So, I first need to naturally sort the string in the second index of every sub-list, then I need to naturally sort all of the lists based on the string in the second index of sub-list.  I have been banging my head against the wall on this all day, so me posting any code that I have tried would probably just lead this down the wrong track.

---

Perhaps my initial sample case wasn't robust enough, but this is the result I am getting based on @Ashwini's code:

```
[[ 1,   'C1', 'DW-00232'],
 [3,    'C11, C32, C46', 'DW-6546'],
 [7,    'C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C25', 'DW-545'],
 [5,    'C2, C3, C4, C5, C63', 'DW-7657'],
 [1,    'C26', 'DW-0056'],
 [2,    'C59, C60', 'DW-23424'],
 [5,    'C6, C13, C24, C30, C64', 'DW-5345']]
```

I would like the output to be as follows:

```
[[ 1,   'C1', 'DW-00232'],
 [5,    'C2, C3, C4, C5, C63', 'DW-7657'],
 [5,    'C6, C13, C24, C30, C64', 'DW-5345'],
 [3,    'C11, C32, C46', 'DW-6546'],
 [7,    'C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C25', 'DW-545'],
 [1,    'C26', 'DW-0056'],
 [2,    'C59, C60', 'DW-23424']]
```

---

***The goal posts keep moving.***  Now I need to consider a case where some of the alpha-numeric combos are in parentheses.  I need to ignore the parenthesis during the sort.

Example:

```
[[ 1, 'C1', 'DW-00232'],
 [ 7, '(C21), C16, (C7), (C18), C19, C6, C65', 'DW-545'],
 [ 5, ' C4, (C2), C3, C10, (C5)', 'DW-7657']]
```

Sorts to this:

```
[[ 1, 'C1', 'DW-00232'],
 [ 5, '(C2), C3, C4, (C5), C10', 'DW-7657'],    
 [ 7, 'C6, (C7), C16, (C18), C19, (C21), C65', 'DW-545']]
```

---

Okay, the above case was an 'easy' fix, once I inspected Ashwini's code a little closer.  I added the translate statement to his natural sort function to the following, based on how he handled his key function (since that was sorting the way I wanted, it was only the per-line sort that wasn't right), as follows.

```
        alphanum_key = (lambda key:
                        [convert(c.translate(None, punctuation + whitespace)) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key)])
```

Comment: Did you mean to specify the second index twice?

Comment: Yes.  The first sort should sort the second index of each sub-list, then the second sort should sort each sub-list based on the second index of each sub-list.  Is that not clear? (not trying to be condescending, I just don't know how clear I am being.)

Comment: Ah, I see now. It's just unusual to want to sort pieces of a string, so I wasn't expecting it; normally it would contain an actual list, which would be sortable as expected.

Comment: Indeed... Inherited the code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `natural_sort` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836734/846892) you can do something like this:

```
import re
from string import punctuation as punc, whitespace as wt
from pprint import pprint

def natural_sort(l): 
    #https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836734/846892
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower() 
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ] 
    return sorted(l, key = alphanum_key)

def key(seq):                                           
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower() 
    return [convert(c.translate(None, punc+wt)) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', seq)]
... 
>>> my_list = [[ 1,   'C1', 'DW-00232'],
 [3,    'C11, C32, C46', 'DW-6546'],
 [7,    'C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C25', 'DW-545'],
 [5,    'C2, C3, C4, C5, C63', 'DW-7657'],
 [1,    'C26', 'DW-0056'],
 [2,    'C59, C60', 'DW-23424'],
 [5,    'C6, C13, C24, C30, C64', 'DW-5345']]
>>> 
>>> new_lis = [x[:1] + [", ".join(natural_sort(x[1].split(', ')))] + x[2:]
                                                                for x in my_list]
>>> new_lis.sort(key = lambda x:key(x[1]))               
>>> pprint(new_lis)
[[1, 'C1', 'DW-00232'],
 [5, 'C2, C3, C4, C5, C63', 'DW-7657'],
 [5, 'C6, C13, C24, C30, C64', 'DW-5345'],
 [3, 'C11, C32, C46', 'DW-6546'],
 [7, 'C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C25', 'DW-545'],
 [1, 'C26', 'DW-0056'],
 [2, 'C59, C60', 'DW-23424']]
>>>
```

Comment: It appears that the first level of natural sort is working correctly, but the second level is not.  

    Item Item Reference
    1 1 A1
2 1 C1
3 3 C11, C32, C46
4 1 C14
5 1 C15
6 7 C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C25
7 5 C2, C3, C4, C5, C63`

Comment: @realityinabox Post the data in question body not in comments.

Comment: An alternative to hand-writing a natural_sort function is to use the `natsort` module.

Answer (score 0):

The default for `sort` is to use the builtin `cmp` to compare elements I think, but you can do, for example:

```
my_list.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
```

That will instruct it to use the first element of every sublist as the comparison key

Edit: without lambdas...

```
from operator import itemgetter
my_list.sort(key = itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: This will only sort the lists. The OP needs to sort the lists _and_ sort the elements in the lists as well.

Comment: And I need all these sorts to be 'natural'.  (ie, A1, A2, A10, A20, not A1, A10, A2, A20)

Comment: Mmh.. For some reason I managed to overlook the sorting of the strings.